# Gap between segments in an SVG doughnut chart

Tags: css, svg

I'm creating a doughnut chart using SVG and CSS, and I would like to add a small gap between the doughnut segments. My values for stroke-dasharray come from Django. This is my code:

```
<div class="dashboard-balance">
  <figure>
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
      <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
      <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#F9FAFC" stroke-width="5"></circle>
      <circle id="income" class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#4E0E7C" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="25.00 75.00" stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
      <circle id="expense" class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#ebebeb" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="75.00 25.00" stroke-dashoffset="100.00"></circle>
      <g class="chart-text">
        <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-number">250.00</text>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-label">Balance</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </figure>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dashboard-balance {
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.chart-text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    fill: #000;
    transform: translateY(0.25em);
}

.chart-number {
    font-size: 0.15em;
    line-height: 1;
    text-anchor: middle;
    transform: translateY(-0.25em);
}

.chart-label {
    font-size: 0.15em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-anchor: middle;
    transform: translateY(0.7em);
}
```

My only idea was to create another circle that would give an illusion of having gaps, but 1) there must be a better solution, 2) I'm not sure how to calculate the values of dasharray for that circle.

Here is the [demo](https://codepen.io/lbastos/pen/MWWBBbO).

Comment: _I'm not sure how to calculate the values of dasharray for that circle._ You may use `stroke-dasharray="1 24 1 74" stroke-dashoffset="25.5"`. Not very elegant though...

Answer (score 3):

The solution could be this:

1. Below is a full gray circle
2. Above the gray circle is the purple circle sector

```
 <circle id="income" class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" 
             stroke="#4E0E7C"  stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray=" 25 0  0 75 " stroke-dashoffset="25">
 </circle>
```

`stroke-dasharray=" 25,0  0,75"` where `25` - dash,`0` - gap  `0` - dash, `75` - gap
`stroke-dashoffset="25"` - Shift the start of the circle counterclockwise by a quarter

3. Using a mask, cut out two narrow strips

```
 <mask id="msk1"> 
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
         <polyline points="21,0 21, 21" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"  />
          <polyline points="21, 21 42 21" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"  />
 </mask>
```

Below is the full code

```html
<style>
.dashboard-balance {
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.chart-text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    fill: #000;
    transform: translateY(0.25em);
}

.chart-number {
    font-size: 0.15em;
    line-height: 1;
    text-anchor: middle;
    transform: translateY(-0.25em);
}

.chart-label {
    font-size: 0.15em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-anchor: middle;
    transform: translateY(0.7em);
}
</style>
<div class="dashboard-balance">
  <figure>
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
      <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle> 
    
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1"> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <polyline points="21,0 21, 21" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"  />
       <polyline points="21, 21 42 21" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"  />
     </mask> 
</defs> 
   
 <g mask="url(#msk1)">
      <circle id="expense" class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent"
        stroke="#ebebeb" stroke-width="5" >
   </circle>  
      <circle id="income" class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" 
       stroke="#4E0E7C"  stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray=" 25 0  0 75 " stroke-dashoffset="25">
   </circle> 
 </g>  
   
   
     
   <g class="chart-text">
        <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-number">250.00</text>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-label">Balance</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </figure>
</div>
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Nice solution. The OP may now decide to remove the `<circle class="donut-hole"` for a nice see-through effect

Comment: @dedmauz69 If the solution is helpful to you, please remember to accept it.